# vs2012 build fails intermittently

Tags: visual-studio-2012, upgrade

I am trying to upgrade a library from vs2010 to vs2012. It is a single sln file with 35 projects. I use devenv.com to build it. The example command to do this looks something like:

> "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\Tools..\IDE\devenv.com" /rebuild "Release|x64" singlesolution.vc12.sln

The behavior is intermittent. It would fail with 2 succeeded projects and 33 failed projects on first invocation. On 2nd invocation it would pass with all 35 successfully built. And on 3rd invocation it would fail. I have switched off the number of parallel builds by setting maximum parallel builds to 1.

Could you please suggest me where i am going wrong? Is this a known behavior with vs2012?

Comment: Somehow built it by cleaning all projects, setting max parallel builds to 1. Weird!